# async / await | Sometimes my code catches errors, sometimes not

Tags: node.js, async-await, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS Lambda with Node.js 10.x and writing my function using async / await. The problem is that sometimes my code catches errors and sometimes not (I believe it doesn't wait for the promises).

My code looks like this:

```
'use strict';

const util = require('util');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const responder = require('./responder.js');

const dbConn = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
  user            : process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  password        : process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  port            : process.env.RDS_PORT,
  database        : process.env.RDS_DATABASE
});

const query = util.promisify(dbConn.query).bind(dbConn);

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    // SAMPLE CODE START
    if (event.httpMethod === 'GET') {

      let arrTextsPromise = textTranslations();
      let arrListsPromise = listNames();

      arrTexts = await arrTextsPromise;
      arrLists = await arrListsPromise;

      return responder.success(arrTexts);
    }
    // SAMPLE CODE END

  } catch (err) {
    return responder.error(err.message);
  }
}

// SAMPLE FUNCTIONS START
async function textTranslations() {
  try {
    let results = [];

    const sql = `SELECT name, text_en FROM texts`;
    const rows = await query(sql);

    for (let key in rows) {
      results[rows[key]['name']] = rows[key]['text_en'];
    }

    return results;

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
}

async function listNames() {
  try {
    let results = [];

    const sql = `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'list_%'`;
    const rows = await query(sql);

    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      results.push(rows[i]['table_name'].substr(5));
    }

    return results;

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
}
// SAMPLE FUNCTIONS END
```

Everything works great but let's suppose that I set the wrong username for my MySQL database. Sometimes my code will generate the expected actions from my "catch" function and sometimes it will result in an Internal Server Error / UnhandledPromiseRejection.

My code is working fine and catching pretty much every error but as I see that the same error sometimes gets caught and sometimes not makes me thing that something is wrong.

Am I missing something to be able to catch all of those errors/promises with async/await?

Comment: Can it be that you're not handling a promise somewhere else? This code looks ok.

Comment: I don't think so @LEQADA. Just changed my post with some real/tested coded and I keep getting the same issue. 90% of the times the error is handled fine but sometimes I get UnhandledPromiseRejection / Error 500. So there's something wrong with my logic. This usually happens when something is wrong with my MySQL connection (maybe wrong username).

Comment: It seem fine, just only use `try/catch` block one time - at `handle` function. Check again `responder.error` function, maybe this is main reason which throws a `PromiseRejection`